# Get only list of user with latest update by days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to write a query to display list of users that check-in in a day, but if the same user check-in twice or more, it would take the latest in a day. For example user A check-in in the morning, then check-in again in the evening, then the system will display only his latest check-in in the list of users that check-in in that day.

This is my table:

```
CHECKIN_TABLE

id | checkin_datetime        | user_id | office_id
1    2020-12-02 09:07:09.290   1         D01
2    2020-12-02 15:13:42.645   1         D02
3    2020-12-02 12:25:12.823   2         D01
4    2020-12-03 13:12:05.523   1         D01
```

Then I would like to write a query that generate output like this:

```
date       | user_id | office_id
2020-12-02   1         D02
2020-12-02   2         D01
2020-12-03   1         D01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select convert(date, checkin_datetime), user_id, office_id
from CHECKIN_TABLE ct
where ct.checkin_datetime = (select max(ct2.checkin_datetime)
                             from CHECKIN_TABLE ct2
                             where ct2.user_id = ct.user_id and
                                   convert(date, ct2.checkin_datetime) = convert(date, ct.checkin_datetime)
                           );
```

Or you can use `row_number()`:

```
select convert(date, checkin_datetime), user_id, office_id
from (select ct.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ct.user_id, convert(date, ct.checkin_datetime)
                                order by ct.checkin_datetime desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from CHECKIN_TABLE ct
     ) ct
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, c.checkin_datetime) date, c.user_id, c.office_id
FROM CHECKIN_TABLE c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM CHECKIN_TABLE
  WHERE user_id = c.user_id 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, checkin_datetime) = CONVERT(DATE, c.checkin_datetime)
    AND checkin_datetime > c.checkin_datetime
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df90e823f69a01900e636ab18a357104).
Results:

```
> date       | user_id | office_id
> :--------- | ------: | :--------
> 2020-12-02 |       1 | D02      
> 2020-12-02 |       2 | D01      
> 2020-12-03 |       1 | D01
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `[Id]` column is uniqe and auto incremental, Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, [checkin_datetime]) AS [date]
     , user_id
     , office_id
 FROM CHECKIN_TABLE C
 JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(id) AS [id]
     FROM CHECKIN_TABLE
    GROUP BY user_id, office_id
)T ON C.id = T.id
```